# In nested functions, how to make the current function stick only to the returned values of the previous function?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, higher-order-functions

This is an algorithmic question. I want to have a higher order function that can repeatedly receive arguments, like `func(3, 5)(4, 9)(1, 2)(...)`. I know all I need is to define a function that returns a function (an inner function), maybe like this (I'm not sure if this is the correct codes though)

```
def func(a, b = 0):
    def inner_func(c, d):
        nonlocal b
        b += c + d
        print(b)
        ...
        return inner_func
    return inner_func(a, b)
```

So when we run:

```
test0 = func(1, 2)
test1 = test0(2, 3)
```

we should get outputs at least:

```
5
10
```

But if we run:

```
test0 = func(1, 2)
test1 = test0(2, 3)
test_add = test0(2, 3)
```

the output will be:

```
5
10
15
```

However,  I want `test_add = test0(2, 3)` to return exactly the same thing that `test1 = test0(2, 3)` returns, which is 10.

```
Expected outputs:
5
10
10
```

I should find a way to make the current function `test0(2, 3)` stick only to inputs of the previous function `func(1, 2)`, which are `1` and `2`. More examples:

```
test0 = func(1, 2)
test1 = test0(2, 3)

Expected outputs:
5
10

test_add = test0(3, 5)

Expected outputs: 13 
But got: 18
```

So, how should I modify the code for this purpose?

Comment: The typical way to handle this is to have sort of terminator call. Like if the inner function is called with 0 arguments, it return the answer instead of a reference to the function, so it would kind of resemble the builder pattern. I don't know of a way to do literally what you want here though. You would need to have a callable number I would think.

Comment: what about using a generator?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Well, yeah but that is not the way for this task. I'm thinking about appending the value to a list and assigning a unique id to each function called so that I could possibly track the value. But I believe this is a super complicated way and very likely not feasible.

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Could you be a bit more specific? For example, some lines of codes to illustrate your point.

Comment: sorry I couldn't really understand what you are trying to do here, can you be more concise, right now the question seems all over the place, do you need to keep returning new outputs based on the inputs to the function?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Problem is solved. Thanks, anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To chain the outputs, your result must be a callable. But in order to make the call repeatable, your result also has to store an inner state.

It this point, using a function as the result type is the incorrect choice. Combining functionality and inner state is what *classes* are meant for.

Just write a quick helper class that stores the state:

```py
class func_result:
    def __init__(self, prev):
        self.prev = prev
    def __call__(self, a, b):
        val = a+b+self.prev
        print(val)
        return func_result(val)

def func(a, b):
    return func_result(b)(a,b)

test0 = func(1, 2)
test1 = test0(2, 3)
test_add1 = test1(2, 3)
test_add2 = test0(2, 3)
test_add3 = test0(3, 5)
```

```
5
10
15
10
13
```

---

If you don't like the fact that the `func_result` class is now exposed, you can nest it in the function:

```py
def func(a, b):
    class func_result:
        def __init__(self, prev):
            self.prev = prev
        def __call__(self, a, b):
            val = a+b+self.prev
            print(val)
            return func_result(val)
    return func_result(b)(a,b)
```